# How to detect where a header is included from

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to detect (and print out) programmatically where a C++ header got included from?

I have a header like:

```
// DeprecatedHeader.h
__pragma( message ("DeprecatedHeader.h is deprecated - include NewHeader.h instead.") )
#include "NewHeader.h"
```

As you can see, compiler is MSVC, but I have macros to wrap. GCC is welcome, but if not possible, I would enable the 'trick' just on Windows.

But what I'm looking for is an output like

```
"AnyOtherFile.cpp was including DeprecatedHeader.h, please include NewHeader.h instead."
```

Edit: To be clear why I want this: The warning the compiler throws is helping already a lot: the code is not broken but pokes the people to change the include. Problem: it may blame the wrong 'guy' as you could pull in this header via another header. My objective was to blame the erroneous header, not the compilation unit.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do this with a simple text search over your codebase?

Comment: A running a script before your makefile would by far be the easiest

Comment: One word: `/showincludes`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx

Comment: a quick solution is to remove the file and see the include errors generated by the compiler.

Comment: "*programatically*" by means of out of the application in question (the one during which's build the includes were included) or by any other program/tool?

Comment: A search and removing the the file is not really an option. The project is big, consumers of it are not all know. The idea was that in one release it's marked as deprecated, in the next it's removed.

Comment: "programatically" means using commands to let the compiler throwing this warning during normal compilation, opposed to a full-text search (of code I cannot reach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I don't think it's worth pursuing this functionality, but here's a solution.

On top of each header file, after checking for deprecated header and before including other files, put this:

```
#undef INCLUDING_FILE
#define INCLUDING_FILE "file_name.h"
```

This can be done with a simple bash script where for each `.h` file you write this, including the file name in the string.

So your headers would look like this (with gcc):

Normal header:

```
#undef INCLUDING_FILE
#define INCLUDING_FILE "normal.h"

#include "deprecated.h"
```

Deprecated header:

```
#ifdef INCLUDING_FILE
# pragma message "Internal bug: " INCLUDING_FILE " included " __FILE__ " which is deprecated"
#else
# pragma message "Note: you shouldn't included " __FILE__ " which is deprecated"
#endif

#undef INCLUDING_FILE
#define INCLUDING_FILE "normal.h"

#include "others.h"
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about something like this, but this sounds too much effort. I think the warning like it is now is the maximum which is feasible. Thanks anyway for the solution!

Comment: @borph, I also believe this is not worth the hassle, not to mention quite unconventional. Don't forget to upvote/accept the posts that helped you/answered your question.

Comment: I tried, but it came up with "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 2):

You can run your compiler with the option to produce the preprocessed source code rather than the fully compiled (`gcc -E`, `CL.EXE /E` or whatever) . The resulting code will include tagging of where each snippet of code comes from.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for - see comments in the question. Before I consider a pre-build script or so I will leave it as it is - the warning is already "loud", but could blame the wrong people.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about an exact solution (probably it is possible to do with `__FILE__` and other similar macros), but you could try `#warning` preprocessor directive placed into a wrong header file. During compilation it will issue a warning, which will notify about whatever you want.

Comment: __FILE__ refers to current file, I wish there would be a thing referring to the "previous file". The warning is exactly what I do.